# Why is UIActionSheet shown upside-down in UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiactionsheet

I am aware that `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8, but I still need the API because I am still targetting iOS 7.

So here's the problem: My app supports both `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` for phone devices. When my app shows a `UIActionSheet` in normal portrait orientation everything is fine. If the device is turned upside down, however, the action sheet is also displayed upside down, like this:

[image: screenshot]

The problem exists only when the app is run on a device (or in a simulator) with iOS 8. The problem goes away when the app is run in a simulator with iOS 7.1 (I haven't got a real device with iOS 7.1 to test). When my app was still built with a pre-iOS 8 SDK the problem also never occurred, even when the app was run on a device with iOS 8.

Does anyone have a suggestion what I could be doing wrong here? See the code snippet below for a minimal example that reproduces the problem. I am coding with Xcode 6.1.1 and iOS SDK 8.1. I promise that I haven't fiddled with the Xcode app bundle in any way :-)

---

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

1. Create a new Xcode project using the "Single View Application" template
2. Select the main target, then on the "General" tab make sure that the "Upside Down" device orientation is checked
3. Open the main storyboard
4. Add a method named `doIt:` to the first responder
5. Add a new UIButton to the view and connect the button's "Touch Up Inside" event to the method

Finally, add the following code to `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void) doIt:(id)sender
{
  UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"sheet title"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"sheet action"];
  [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

// This override is required so that interface orientation
// to UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown is possible
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Run the app, rotate and tap the button and you should see what I mean.

Comment: It simply looks like the `UIActionSheet` isn't rotating to the portrait upside down orientation, right?

Comment: @mattsven Yes, that's correct. As you can see in the screenshot, the sheet is dropping downwards from the top of the screen, and the text is all upside down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ios 8 , i think you had better use the UIAlertController instead. It will be better to deal with this strange case.

Comment: If by "strange case" you mean "strange behaviour of `UIActionSheet`", then I am all with you.

Comment: Also the alterview , these the deprecate controller will be something wrong after the 8.1 in my app.

Comment: @herzbube He's right - this is actually probably the simplest solution to your problem if it fixes this issue. Use `UIActionSheet` for anything below iOS 8 and `UIAlertViewController` for anything `>=`.

Comment: @mattsven It does solve the issue, so in the end I grudgingly followed your and Feng's advice. Although not pretty code, it is, by far, the most pragmatic solution.